# Fading to a Vanishing Point in Flash, Programatically (of course)

Tags: flash, transformation, scale9grid

I'm trying to do a vanishing Star Wars type thing like [this](http://www.freehandsource.com/_frames/_tips/_archive/tip_week103.html), but programatically.

Most of what they've done is easy to program (make a motion tween), but I wish to generate the text-based graphic programatically as well (from text using a dynamic text obj, for example).

**The question, as I see it** (but I'm open to other ways of seeing it, of course) **is: is there any way to get a slanty-sided rectangle from my dynamic-text object?** The scale9grid mentioned [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#scale9Grid) will not do it, I'm quite sure. I want to specify four points to get a rhombus (if that's what it's called).

Comment: (in reply to your comment) It's the way actionscript works, each new player iteration introduces some new api's. The 3D stuff is new for Flash player 10. I'm sure you can set CS4 to do plain player 9 stuff too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are compiling for flash player 10 (which requires CS4 or a recent flex sdk), you can just rotate the text field in 3d:

```
text.rotateX = -45;
```

There are a few more issues with this, such as you need to use font embedding, and getting the vanishing point in the center of the field.

Doing this in flash player < 10 with bitmaps is also possible, if you are masochistic, and don't mind some vertical aliasing. The idea would be to use BitmapData.draw() to draw each line with a height 1 clipping rect and a transform to do the perspective division. Eg (in flex):

```
class Main extends Sprite
{
    [Embed(systemFont="Arial", fontName="embedFont", mimeType="application/x-font")]
    var embedFont:Class;

    public function Main()
    {
        var text:TextField = new TextField();
        text.defaultTextFormat = new TextFormat("embedFont", 30);
        text.embedFonts = true;
        text.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
        text.text = "Hello, world\nHow nice\nto have\nmultiple\nlines!";
        var bmp:BitmapData = new BitmapData(150, 100);

        for (var i:int = 0; i != bmp.height; ++i) {
            var m:Matrix = new Matrix();
            // x-division, change 0.8, 0.2 to change scale increase, scale at top
            m.a = i*(0.8/bmp.height)+0.2;
            // horizontal center
            m.tx = bmp.width * (1-m.a) / 2;
            // y-division, and align text to bottom
            m.ty = (bmp.height-i)/m.a - bmp.height; 
            bmp.draw(text, m, null, null, new Rectangle(0, i, bmp.width, 1));
        }

        addChild(new Bitmap(bmp));
    }
}
```

I haven't done the maths, so I don't know if that's physically accurate, but it should give you an idea.

Comment: Lovely... I mean, the CS4 thing. The other one is somewhat painful. Nice work on the loop. Now I guess I'll actually have to use/debug this stuff, since I've gotten innocent people involved :)

Comment: Wow, just tried out your CS3 code... great stuff. Now I'll have to... oh forget it, I'll post a link here when it's done. THANKS AGAIN SIMON.

Comment: Still not sure if the the fonts are going to look too crappy, but here's a first HelloWorld http://confusionstudio.com/starwars001.swf, pure Flex code (with the swcs from Flash imported, of course).

Comment: Hmm... looks like you are moving it in screen-y, rather than text-y. An easy way around that is "var p = new Sprite(); p.addChild(text); p.rotateX = -45; ... text.y -= 10;". Or is that the Flash 9 code?

Comment: Hey, it was the Flash 9 code. On the other hand, I think that the squashed bitmap looks pixelated, and I bettered it a bunch by doing everything HUGE and scaling, but it's still not pretty.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not scaling properly in the y-direction, so you get bad aliasing - might look at this tonight. Try re-drawing the bitmap each frame with `m.ty = ... - frameNo * speed;` for better scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider converting the text object to an image, and then doing that to the image.

-Adam

Comment: yeah, I believe that no image would work. those kinds of distortion transforms, at least in the flash cs4 interface, only work with certain types of objects. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really do this in a simple way in Flash Player 9 and earlier.
Flash player 10 and Flash CS4 introduces some basic support for 3D transformations, but these are quite simple, and i guess this "extreme" perspective could be tricky to get right. I have however not used the CS4 authoring tool, so it might be easier in there.

There are also the full 3D engines like [papervision](http://blog.papervision3d.org/) and [away3d](http://away3d.com/) although they are a bit overkill.

What I think might be best is using a [DisplacementMapFilter](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/filters/DisplacementMapFilter.html), I had some trouble finding any good examples of this online, and I've never actually done it myself, but I think the [example in the docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/filters/DisplacementMapFilter.html#includeExamplesSummary) should get you started just fine.

If you feel up for it you *can* also just draw all the pixels to a bitmap and have at them one by one, that might be the most fun thing to code, but it will likely be quite slow and not look as good ;)

Comment: I did not know that CS4 and CS3 talk to different Flash APIs. Interesting. I just tried out the DisplacementFilterMap example and it looks like it will work just fine for Flash Player 9 (CS3), but man those 3D transforms for CS4 are attractive. Thanks for your answer.